# pytorch CUDA out of memory when using distributed training - numbers don't sum up

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

When training using Torch Distributed Elastic (with 2 machines each having 2 GPUs) and DataLoader with 2 workers I got out of memory error:

> RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 148.00 MiB (GPU 0; 15.90 GiB total capacity; 314.95 MiB already allocated; 128.75 MiB free; 342.00 MiB reserved in total by PyTorch)"

It's really strange because the card has 15.90 GiB and when only small amount is reserved and allocated there is only 128.75 MiB free.

Is there any reason that could cause it? Do you have any suggestions how I could debug it?

Comment: Are you the only one using the GPU, or is it shared among other users or processes?